# Add additional Eloquent Model Join before executing Query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have below requirement of joining additional Model `city` before executing the query.

Here in the below code, `timezone` column is in `city` table.

```
$this->user->dishwasher->jobs()
->whereBetween("start_date_time", ["convert_tz( now() + interval 1440 minute, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)", "convert_tz(NOW()+ INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)"])
->get();
```

I tried adding `with` property on `Dishwasher` modal

```
class Dishwasher extends Model {
    protected $with = ['city'];
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function jobs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
    }
    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\City");
    }
}
```

Also I tried adding `with` property.

```
$this->user->dishwasher->jobs()
->whereBetween("start_date_time", ["convert_tz( now() + interval 1440 minute, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)", "convert_tz(NOW()+ INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)"])
->with(['city'])
->get();
```

But at the end I ended up in one query only,

```
select 
`jobs`.*, 
`dishwasher_jobs`.`dishwasher_id` as `pivot_dishwasher_id`, 
`dishwasher_jobs`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id`, 
`dishwasher_jobs`.`id` as `pivot_id`
from `jobs` 
inner join `dishwasher_jobs` on `jobs`.`id` = `dishwasher_jobs`.`job_id` 
where `dishwasher_jobs`.`dishwasher_id` = ? 
and `start_date_time` between ? and ?
```

May I know how I can add additional joins of modal, so that I can use in `where` condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add where clause on relationship model use `whereHas()` method. Also if you want to select `jobs()` with dishwasher add it also in `with()` method. So if i understand correctly you should have code like this:

```
$this->user->dishwasher()
->whereHas('city',function($query) use($this->configTimeZone) { // i don't know what $this->configTimeZone is so if it is variable you will need to use it like this in closure
     $query->whereBetween("start_date_time", ["convert_tz( now() + interval 1440 minute, 
            '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)", "convert_tz(NOW()+ INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE, 
            '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)"])
})
->with(['city','jobs'])
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with your code, ```start_date_time``` column is not found, this column is in jobs table.
Blow is the code.
```
$this->user->dishwasher->whereHas('city', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereBetween("start_date_time", ["convert_tz( now() + interval 1440 minute, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)", "convert_tz(NOW()+ INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE, '$this->configTimeZone', timezone)"]);
            })->with(['city', 'jobs'])->get();
```